# Softlayer API: Image Device 2's disk type

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I am having issue creating instance from an image with device 2. I have 3 images:

1. image 1 is generated from an instance with local disk 0 25G and disk 2 25 G. I have no issue to create instance from this image with Local or San disk type.
2. image 2 is generated from an instance with San disk 0 25 G and disk 2 10 G. I got exception from SL "SoftLayer_Exception_Public Provider Error: At least 2 LOCAL disks are required but your order has 1. Revisit your selections and disk types." if I pick "local" disk type when creating instance from this image. "San" disk type works fine.
3. image 3 is generated from an instance with San disk 0 25 G and disk 2 25G. I have no issue to create instance from this image with Local or San disk type.

My question is, how can I know an image with device 2 will only support local or san or both disk types?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This error doesn't means that the image only supports LOCAL disks, it means that you didn't provide the **price id** for the second local disk when calling to [placeOrder](https://softlayer.github.io/reference/services/SoftLayer_Product_Order/placeOrder/) method.

> SoftLayer_Exception_Public Provider Error: At least 2 LOCAL disks are
>   required but your order has 1.

All images support LOCAL or SAN disks, the creation of virtual guests depends on the availability of prices, on this case there isn't an available price for **10 GB (LOCAL)**

If you are using [createObject](https://softlayer.github.io/reference/services/SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest/createObject/) method take in count that this looks for available items based on your request and performs a **placeOrder** call.

You can use the method [getCreateObjectOptions](https://softlayer.github.io/reference/services/SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest/getCreateObjectOptions/) to know the available items that can be set on **createObject**. Use [getItemPrices](https://softlayer.github.io/reference/services/SoftLayer_Product_Package/getItemPrices/) with the **package 835** if you are using **placeOrder**.

Comment: I see. Thank you!